# Почему не сохраняется переменная в json?

Tags: python, json, tkinter

https://pastebin.com/64w5zQpF - вот пастбин. Не сохраняется переменная `cont` в строку `"content"` в json, а появляется просто пустота, то есть `"content": ""`.
Код фрагмента с проблемой:

```
def noteedit():
    window1 = Tk()
    window1.geometry('900x600')
    window1.title('Редактирование заметки')
    text = Text(window1)
    text.place(x=1, y=10)

    def textget():
        global cont
        cont = text.get(1.0, END)
        print(cont)

    newnote = {
        "content": cont
    }
    with open("./notes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(newnote, f)
        print(f)
    b3 = Button(window1)
    b3.place(x=10, y=400, width = 120, height = 40)
    b3.configure(text='Сохранить', command=textget)
```

Прошу заметить, что ошибки нет. Просто не сохраняется переменная в строку json.

Comment: во-первых нужно вставить код в вопрос

Comment: @SKIP код на 100 строк, ужасно выглядело бы

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @EXTERMINATED никто не будет искать в сто строках где у вас проблема, добавьте тот момент, где не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция textget, в которой происходит заполнение переменной cont, у вас вызывается в момент нажатия кнопки. А вы пытаетесь получить значение переменной до того как кнопка нажата, даже до того как кнопка создана. Нужно перенести сохранение в файл внутрь функции textget, чтобы сохранение также происходило после нажатия на кнопку:

```
def textget():
    cont = text.get(1.0, END)
    print(cont)

    newnote = {
        "content": cont
    }
    with open("./notes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(newnote, f)

b3 = Button(window1)
b3.place(x=10, y=400, width = 120, height = 40)
b3.configure(text='Сохранить', command=textget)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!